# Where on screen is allowed to put admob ads?

Tags: android, admob

Is there any rules about positioning admob ads?
I know there should be only one ad per page if it is not scrollable and
maximum two if it is scrollable(one visible) and that should not be near buttons and similar.
Does it have to be positioned at the bottom(or top)? Can it be positioned for example 50dp from the bottom or in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be placed anywhere you want it to be. However, it is not recommended not to be placed in between the screen as it hamper user expereince.

Comment: Thanks, user experience doesn't matter to much because I'm developing game not serius application so if it's not against rules ad placed in the middle of screen is even better for me (maybe more clicks).